# How to create an array of JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, json, vb.net

I'm trying to create an array of JSON objects in javascript.  When I view the object in the debugger (VS.NET 2010), I only see the first object's fields/values but no array.

```
var myjsonarray = [{
  ID:1,
  FirstName: "test1"
},{
  ID:2,
  FirstName: "test2"
}];
```

For myjsonarray, the debugger shows:

```
ID = 1
FirstName = "test1"
```

When I view myjsonarray.length, length is undefined.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, what you have there isn't JSON. They're JavaScript [literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Literals). If you are attempting to use that as JSON, it will fail to parse as `var`, identifiers, `=`, or `;` are not supported as they are in JavaScript.

Comment: This seems to be an IE issue again (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621620/why-does-ajax-post-fail-with-invalid-argument#comment27414723_18621620).  I tried it with FF and it is fine.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: Do you have a JSON example?

Comment: @4thSpace My point was just that you're mixing up the names. You have JavaScript here, but are calling it JSON. They have a strong relation since JSON's syntax was taken from parts of JavaScript's literals syntax. But, JSON is a data format; not code. So, you probably want to stick with JavaScript.

Comment: There is no JSON here.

Comment: That is an array of objects, just not JSON, simply JavaScript objects, `alert(myjsonarray[0].FirstName);` alerts "test1" `alert(myjsonarray[1].FirstName);` alerts "test2"